# Bonferroni correction in MANOVA

Tags: manova, bonferroni

so if I've done a MANOVA and followed that up with Bonferroni correction and found that only 2 out of 7 variables are significant (whereas before there were a few more) does that mean that only these 2 variables are significant overall then and I only talk about them in my study? Hopefully this makes sense! Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the community. Can you please contextualise your question more? Why do you do this multiple comparison? Why are you doing MANOVA to begin with? Etc. (Some punctuation would be appreciated too.) You can edit the original post of your question by clicking the `edit` link below the tags.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally best to report all the tests you performed, whether they were significant or not.

Comment: This may be all that can be said here, but it might be preferable if you could explain this a little more. Eg, why is it "generally best"? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Because honesty is the best policy.